# numpy 2-D array finding exact 2-D array in it

Tags: arrays, numpy

In this case I have a 2-D numpy array of 3x5, and I want to find unique 2-D arrays in this 3x5, for example:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

and I want to find a 2x2 of 1s in this 2-D array, it should return true,
so it may look like this

```
A = [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.],
     [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.],
     [0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]

B = [[1. 1.],
     [1. 1.]]

somfunction(A,B)
=> True
```

Comment: do you want to elaborate more? You want to check if B is in A?

Comment: Yes, just checking if A contains 2-d array like B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a brute force solution:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

B = np.array([[1, 1],
              [1, 1]])
 
def isequal(A, B):
  if np.sum(A-B) == 0:
    return True
  return False

def isBinA(A, B):
  if B.shape[0] > A.shape[0] or B.shape[1] > A.shape[1]:
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(A.shape[0]-B.shape[0]+1):
      for j in range(A.shape[1]-B.shape[1]+1):
        if isequal(A[i:i+B.shape[0], j:j+B.shape[1]], B):
          # edit to change A's value
          A[i:i+B.shape[0], j:j+B.shape[1]] = 2 * B # or any value you want.
          return True
    return False

print(isBinA(A, B))
```

The recursive solution:

```
def isBinA_rec(A, B, i, j):
AA = A[i:i+B.shape[0],j:j+B.shape[1]]
if AA.shape[0] == B.shape[0] and AA.shape[1] == B.shape[1] and np.sum(AA-B) == 0:
    return True
if i >= A.shape[0] - B.shape[0] or j >= A.shape[1] - B.shape[1]:
    return False
return isBinA_rec(A, B, i+1, j) or isBinA_rec(A, B, i, j+1) or isBinA_rec(A, B, i+1, j+1)
```

We can call it like

```
print(isBinA_rec(A, B, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfect! Just one more question, what if I want to change the element at the same time of the original array. Say I found a 2*2 of 1s in array A, now I want to convert that 2*2 of 1s to 2*2 of 0s.

Comment: edited the code, look at the code. Please accept this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi Added the recursive solution as well.